# in Ruby on Rails, why does "form_for @story" has to have Story as RESTful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

It seems that when we use

```
form_for @story do |f|
```

then Story has to be a RESTful resource and it has to be

```
map.resources :stories
```

in the routes.rb.

Can Story be not RESTful?  Can it be a form for non-RESTful data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [rails documentation for form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M001572).

You can modify the `form_for @story` and pass in some other options to suit your needs.

If that doesn't work for you, you can use [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001697) instead.